# how to set a github token for github pages deploy

Tags: authentication, deployment, angular-cli, token, github-pages

Until a few days ago I was deploying my html on Github pages with:
`ng deploy --base-href=/documentation/`

Today I get this error: "remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/BioComputingUP/ProSeqViewer-documentation.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

I have set a token on my github settings, but I don't understand how to use it to deploy my pages. How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered 2 ways:

1. use the token when the IDE prompt asks for the password. I have tested this end it works.
2. set keys. (I have not tested this).